# Instanciar classe com injeção de dependência

Tags: java, injeção-de-dependência

Eu tenho um método que chama outros métodos que não são pré-definidos, estou utilizando essa biblioteca `org.reflections` e o método `java.lang.reflect.Method#invoke` para executar outro método genericamente, esse método`(invoke)` recebe o primeiro parâmetro com a instancia da classe do método que vou executar e os outros parâmetros são os `args` dos método que vai ser executado, tipo assim:

```
metodo.invoke(new InstanciaDaClasse(), args...);
```

O problema é, estou executando esse `invoke` e passando como primeiro parâmetro uma nova instancia de uma classe que tem uma propriedade injetada, ela tem isso:

```
@Inject
UsuarioController usuarioController;
```

O problema é q o método q eu to executando precisa desse `usuarioController`, só que criando uma nova instancia da classe com esse `@Inject` essa propriedade fica `null`, tem algum jeito de criar uma nova instancia de uma classe sem perder as injeções de dependências em runtime ou fazer uma injeção de dependência "artificial"?

Comment: Por que não passar a instância injetada da classe que você precisar invocar?

Comment: @nullptr porque eu não sei que classe que eu vou instanciar, e não sei como injeto uma classe que eu não sei qual é, eu estou fazendo um método genérico que executa outros métodos de classes que podem ter injeção de dependência

Comment: Não sei bem se eu entendi a pergunta, mas de acordo com o que entendi pq vc precisa passar a classe do método que vai executar e os parâmetros dele? Qual o motivo disso?

Comment: @Gustavo o motivo é que eu preciso executar um método genérico, então eu encontrei um modo que é do jeito que eu falei ali na pergunta, o que eu expliquei na pergunta é como executar um método genericamente, e tá certo, funciona, o problema é quando esse método for de uma classe que injeta outra classe, pq eu preciso de uma instancia da classe pra poder executar o método, entendeu?

Comment: O que você pode ter é um mapa com todas suas classes injetadas, e neste seu método voce passar o tipo de classe desejado ao invés da instância, e buscar a instância desse mapa.

Comment: Na sua classe `new InstanciaDaClasse()` pode ter um construtor que receba a classe a injetada. AI vc passa como parametro `new InstanciaDaClasse(new ClasseInjetada())`. Eu não sei qual a lógica do seu programa e tem pouco código pra ser específico. Talvez uma opção sejar usar a anotação `@Qualifier` tbm. Difícil dizer

Comment: @nullptr e Gustavo olhem a minha classe: https://github.com/brunoeas/poc-websocket-java/blob/master/src/main/java/br/com/poc_websocket_java/configuration/WebSocketConfiguration.java
na linha 119, o método `invokeEventMethod ` chama outro método "genericamente", eu consegui resolver o problema fazendo um método que faz uma "injeção de dependências artificial", mas não me orgulho desse método não, me parece errado, caso queiram opinar, a vontade

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema mas não da melhor maneira possível, acredito eu, então não vou considerar o problema como resolvido.

`A intenção` era executar um método genericamente, pra isso eu uso o método `java.lang.reflect.Method#invoke` da biblioteca `org.reflections`, esse método recebe 2 ou mais parâmetros, o primeiro é uma instância da classe do método que vou executar, o segundo e os próximos parâmetros são considerados parâmetros do método que vou executar, exemplo:

```
metodoQueVaiSerExecutado.invoke(new ClasseDoMetodoQueVaiSerExecutado(), ...args);
```

`O problema` é que algumas classes tem injeção de dependências, e apenas instanciando a classe dessa forma faria com que suas dependências ficasses nullas.

`A "solução"` criei um método que instância a classe, as dependências e as dependências das dependências, em resumo é isso:

```
/**
 * Injeta as dependências da classe e de todas suas dependências e retorna
 * uma nova instância da classe
 * 
 * @param classe - Classe que vai ser manipulada
 * @return Uma nova instância da classe passada por parâmetro
 * @throws Exception - Exception genérica
 */
private Object injectDependenciesAndReturnNewInstance(final Class<?> classe) throws Exception {

    final Object classToReturn = classe.newInstance();

    for (final Field field : classe.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (!field.isAnnotationPresent(Inject.class)) {
            continue;
        }
        field.setAccessible(true);

        field.set(classToReturn, this.injectDependenciesAndReturnNewInstance(field.getType()));
    }

    return classToReturn;
}
```

Então o método `invoke` ficou assim:

```
metodo.invoke(this.injectDependenciesAndReturnNewInstance(classe), ...args);
```

Para mais detalhes podem me perguntar, e se ajuda tem o link dessa classe que estou fazendo no meu repositório: https://github.com/brunoeas/poc-websocket-java/blob/master/src/main/java/br/com/poc_websocket_java/configuration/WebSocketConfiguration.java

Se alguém tiver alguma ideia diferente que possa resolver o problema pode mandar